Django - Failed Login Redirecting To Different Page
I am new to Django and I am trying to use the authentication system. I have managed to get it working using the default Auth URLS. (/accounts/login) etc.
I want to get a login form on my homepage so it is always available to unauthenticated users. I have managed to display the form, and when a user enters correct details, the login is successful. Unfortunately when the user enters wrong information it is currently redirecting me to the login url (accounts/login) I have been trying to rectify this, but I either break the auth or it redirects, I cannot seem to find a solution.
Views.py:
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', { 'form': form })

HTML template:
<form class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded-3 bg-body-tertiary" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input class="form-control" id="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}" name="username" type="text" />
                        <label for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}">{{ form.username.label }}</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input class="form-control" id="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}" name="password" type="password" />
                        <label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}">{{ form.password.label }}</label>
                    </div>

                    {% if form.errors %}
                        <div class="justify-content-center d-flex w-75 mt-1 mb-1 alert alert-danger border-0">
                            <small class="text-center mx-4">Your Username and Password Did Not Match!</small>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <input class="w-100 btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></input>
                    
                    <a class="text-center pb-3 text-decoration-none" href="{% url 'register' %}"><small class="text-muted">Don't have an account?</small></a>
</form>

urls.py
path('', views.index, name="home"),

I have tried editing the action in the form so it takes me to Home or removing the action altogether however this then breaks the auth.

The problem here is that the AuthenticationForm doesn't handle the authentication logic for you; it is purely a validation form. You have to use Django's authenticate and login functions to handle the login requests directly in your view.
Updated views.py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
def index(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST or None)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')  # Redirect to home after successful login
        
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})




Look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52486424/show-error-message-if-password-and-username-incorrect-in-django-form-template

This worked for me, I just had to change the action of the form to {% url 'home' %} instead of login and the view to this one! Thanks so much :)
